# django self relation, bulk parent set

Tags: django, parent, children

i have this model

```
class ModelData(models.Model):
    parent_data = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

there is a way to change set a parent in a bulk of selected childrens in admin or a way to edit the parents in admin.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... how about inlines? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-inlines

Comment: in inline i cant just associate parent vs child, i need to create childs in same time of parent.

Comment: You can create the parent and children at the same time with inlines. When you submit the form, it creates the parent first before the children, but it's seamless. What's the issue?

Comment: i already have the parent and the childrens i just wanna associate childrens with parents.